# Avoid discarding old entries in MemoryHandler

Tags: java, logging

When logging to a MemoryHandler, the MemoryHandler removes older entries when the numofentries > size.

I want to avoid this behavior, or at least mark down to the log that older entries are suppressed.

Little test case:

```
import java.util.logging.*;
public class SSCE01 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
        rootLogger.removeHandler(rootLogger.getHandlers()[0]); //remove default Console Handler

        ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
        Logger l = Logger.getLogger("test");
        MemoryHandler mh = new MemoryHandler(ch,3,Level.OFF);
        l.addHandler(mh);

        l.severe("this shouldnt be logged");
        l.severe("this shouldnt be logged");
        l.severe("this shouldnt be logged");
        l.severe("this should be logged");
        l.severe("this should be logged");
        l.severe("this should be logged");

        mh.push();

    }
}
```

Comment: see new edition of the answer I think now it gets closer to what you need. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea, you'll fill the memory machine with traces. Despite this, `MemoryHandle` is a circular buffer so when it gets filled other entries will be removed. If you want entries to not be removed just construct it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as size - again this a bad idea. This will collide with your app performance, and people tend to avoid that.

Consider using a handler that dumps traces into secondary storage, add a timestamp; and build whatever logic you need using the traces from there.

**Edit**

From the code you reported, you could encapsulate your logging functionality in another class that records the number of entries in `MemoryHandler`. Something like:

```
class MyMemoryConsoleHandler {
 private Logger rootLogger;
 private MemoryHandler mh;
 private Logger l;
 private int size = 3;
 private int entries = 0;
 public MyMemoryConsoleHandler() {
    this.rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
    this.rootLogger.removeHandler(rootLogger.getHandlers()[0]);
    ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
    this.l = Logger.getLogger("test");
    this.mh = new MemoryHandler(ch,this.size,Level.OFF);
 }

 public synchronized void push() {
    this.mh.push();
    if (this.entries > this.size) {
        this.l.severe("Entries in log discarded !!!");
        this.mh.push();
    }
    this.entries = 0;
 }

 public synchronized void addMessage(String m) {
    this.entries++;
    this.l.severe(m);
 }
}
```

Instead of using Java API's logging calls directly use your `MyMemoryConsoleHandler` so that you have control over what is pushed to the console.

Pay attention to `synchronized` methods, this is needed in case you have a multi-threaded application. Otherwise you could end up with race conditions.

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE isn't just a bad idea, it is not viable, because 
MemoryHandler mh = new MemoryHandler(new ConsoleHandler(), Integer.MAX_VALUE, Level.OFF); 
on a standard-launched jvm (no -Xmx java option) causes immediately the allocation of an array with Integer.MAX_VALUE elements and so the throwing of a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. The memory isn't used just "in case of huge log", the memory is used in each case!

Comment: @AgostinoX ... ok then ... it's a EXTREMELY bad idea ;)

Comment: i think this misses the point. My logrecord mean number will probably by 100 or less. But i cannot exclude before that wont be cases that exceed this number. If MemoryHandler was implemented with an arraylist, the idea of using an exceedingly large size would work just perfectly. Since it is not, the "use case" of MemoryHandler changes a bit.

Comment: @AgostinoX see new edition of the answer I think now it gets closer to what you need. I hope it helps.